# Check if function is injective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

$$f: N \times N → N$$
$$f(m,n)=m+n+2$$

Function should be injective if $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$
Should I put a,b = c,d or a,b = b,a?

$$a+b+2=c+d+2$$

$$a+b=c+d$$

If a+b = c+d, doesn't that mean it's injective? Thats how I got told, how the answer says it's not injective, what I am not understanding here?

Comment: $4 + 5 = 6+3$.  DOes that mean $4 = 6$ and $5 = 3$?

Comment: "Function should be injective if f(a,b)=f(c,d) "  No.   Function is injective if the *only* times you have $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$ is when $a=c$ and $b=d$.  It is not injective if $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ is possible *without* $a$ having to equal to $c$ and $b$ having to equal $d$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injective means:

> Whenever $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ that is *ONLY* possible if $a=c$ and $b=d$.  If it is ever possible the that $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ but we *don't* need to have *both* $a=c$ and $b=d$ then it is *not* injective.

So if $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ does that mean we *have* to have $a=c$ and $b=d$?

If $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ then

$a + b + 2 = c + d + 2$ and so

$a+b = c+d$.

But that's as far as we can go.  We *could* have $a =c$ and $b=d$ but we don't *have* to.    We could have $a=d$ and $b =c$.  Or we could have $a= c+3$ and $b=d-3$.  Or we could have $a = c+d$ and $b = 0$.  Or we could have any number of different ways of doing this.

Perhaps easy to note just do  counter example.  $f(1,2)= 1+2 + 2= 5$ and $f(2,1) = 2+1 + 2 = 5$ so $f(1,2) = f(2,1)$.  But we do *not* have $1=2$ and we do *not* have $2=1$ so it is not injective.

Of $f(3,4) = 3+4+ 2 = 9$ but $f(5,2)=5+2 + 2=9$.  So $f(3,4)=f(5,2)$.  But $3\ne 5$ and $4 \ne 2$.  So it is *not* injective.

...

Perhaps an example of a function that *is* injective might be in order.

Consider $g(n,m) = 2^n \times 3^m$.

So if $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$ does this *force* $a=c$ and $b = d$?  (The answer will be, surprisingly maybe, "yes").

If $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$ then we have $2^a3^b = 2^c3^d$.

Case 1:  Suppose $a < c$.  Then $2^a3^b = 2^c3^d$ so

$3^b = \frac {2^c3^d}{2^a} = 2^{c-a}3^d$.

BUt $c -a > 0$ so $2^{c-a}3^d$ is even but $3^b$ is odd.  SO that is impossible.

Case 2:  Suppose $a > c$.

Then $2^a3^b = 2^c3^d$ so

$\frac {2^a3^b}{2^c} = 3^d$ and $2^{a-c}3^b = 3^d$.

BUt $a -b > 0$ so $2^{a-c}3^b$ is even but $3^d$ is odd.  SO that is impossible.

So $a< c$ is impossible.  And $a > c$ is impossible.

So we *MUST* have $a = c$.  If $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$ then we are *forced* to have $a=c$.

So final case:  If $a = c$ (last remaining option)

then

Then $2^a 3^b = 2^c3^d = 2^a 3^d$ so

$\frac {2^a3^b}{2^a}=\frac {2^a3^d}{2^a}$ so

$3^b = 3^d$ so

$\log_3 3^b = \log_3 3^d$ so

$b = d$.  So $a=c$ and $b =d$.

So we were *forced* to have both $a = c$ and $b=d$.  If $g(a,b) = g(c,d)$ that is *only* possible when $a=c$ and $b = d$.

So in that case $g$ *IS* injective.

But $f(n,m) = n+ m + 2$ is *NOT*.

Answer (score 2):

Being injective means that when $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$, then $(a,b)=(c,d)$. But $f(1,2)=f(2,1)$, in spite of the fact that $(1,2)\ne(2,1)$. So, $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Why does $(1,2)≠(2,1)$ if the result will be the same? It will be 5 = 5

Comment: Why do we have $(1,2)\ne(2,1)$? Because, for instance, the first component of $(1,2)$ is $1$ whereas the first component of $(2,1)$ is $2$. Yes, $f(1,2)=f(2,1)=5$. And it is *precisely* because $(1,2)\ne(2,1)$ and $f(1,2)=f(2,1)$ that $f$ is *not* injective.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler counter example is $f(3,7) = 3 + 7 + 2 = 12$.  And $f(4,6) = 4 + 6 + 2 =12$.  So $f(3,7) = f(4,6)$.  But the pair $(3,7)$  is not the same pair as $(4,6)$. The are completely different pairs.  Likewise the pair $(1,2)$ is not the same pair as $(2,1)$ because they are in different order so they are *different* pairs. You seem to be confusing what is required.  It's not when the *results* are the same.  It's when the *only* way the result can be the same is when the input are the same.  That is *not* the case here.